# Leaflet & special characters

Tags: leaflet, unicode

I have a problem regarding Leaflet and calvinmetcalf's shapefile module. In my shapefile I have fields and in those fields are strings like:

```
'Frankfurt'
'Tübingen'
'Géramer-sur-Mer'
```

You see that due to the special characters in the shapefile fields, on my Leaflet I get strange outputs. I think that is due to the UTF-8 restrictions. Since my data is not loaded on a regular webpage using a .html file, but using a Sharepoint webpart, how on earth can I show the special characters? For sure, I added above the `<meta charset="utf-8"/>`. Am I missing something?

Comment: You'll need to provide more information - how does the output look like and, if possible, details about the encoding of the shapefile text (do you have a `.cpg` sidecar file?). Utilities like `ogrinfo` (https://gdal.org/programs/ogrinfo.html#ogrinfo) will display that kind of metadata from the shapefile.

Comment: The metadata shows correctly UTF-8 and the `.cpg`-file even has this info saved.

Answer (score 1):

utf-8 can display pretty much anything - characters up to 4 bytes gives, as you probably know, about 4 billion possible characters. In fact, utf-8 is about the least restrictive character set there is (hence the wide use).

"strange outputs" is a poor substitute for a screenshot, but there are a few things worth checking:

1. Is the input data (the shapefile) in utf-8?
2. Does the shapefile display correctly in, eg qgis/openlayers/whatever else is handy?
3. What characters are actually being parsed from the Shapefile (ie via `console.log()`)
4. Does the font you are using have glyphs for those special characters

If it were me, I'd go for #2 first and use that to do #1 if I could do it in 5 minutes or less, and then move to #3, which should give you some insight on #4.

Comment: 1) According to FME & QGIS the shapefile is in UTF-8 format. 2) Shapefile does display correctly. Only the special characters are not showing correctly. 3) I checked that console.log()-thing but I do not see how and what to do there. 4) I use the standard Leaflet font (I used the example from the Leaftlet page and only loaded the shapefile in it).